# Quicklisp install errors

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, quicklisp

I am trying to install quicklisp into my Lisp REPL but am getting errors. I am running Ubuntu 21.10 and have tried installing quicklisp in both GNU clisp 2.49.92 and sbcl 2.1.1-debian. I have tried with both the latest download of quicklisp from lispcookbook.github.io and using the cl-quicklisp package in the Ubuntu repos. The errors I get are

```
GNU CLISP 2.49.92
=================
    [1]> (load "quicklisp")
    ;; Loading file /home/david/quicklisp.lisp ...

    ==== quicklisp quickstart 2015-01-28 loaded ====

        To continue with installation, evaluate: (quicklisp-quickstart:install)

        For installation options, evaluate: (quicklisp-quickstart:help)

    ;; Loaded file /home/david/quicklisp.lisp
    #P"/home/david/quicklisp.lisp"
    [2]> (quicklisp-quickstart:install)

    *** - OS-ERROR(EINVAL): Invalid argument
    The following restarts are available:
    ABORT          :R1      Abort main loop
    Break 1 [3]> 


SBCL 2.1.1-debian
=================
    * (load "quicklisp.lisp")

    ==== quicklisp quickstart 2015-01-28 loaded ====

        To continue with installation, evaluate: (quicklisp-quickstart:install)

        For installation options, evaluate: (quicklisp-quickstart:help)

    T
    * (quicklisp-quickstart:install)

    debugger invoked on a SB-BSD-SOCKETS:TRY-AGAIN-ERROR in thread
    #<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {1004C00173}>:
    Name service error in "getaddrinfo": -3 (Temporary failure in name resolution)

    Type HELP for debugger help, or (SB-EXT:EXIT) to exit from SBCL.

    restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):
    0: [ABORT] Exit debugger, returning to top level.

    (SB-BSD-SOCKETS:NAME-SERVICE-ERROR "getaddrinfo" -3)
    error finding frame source: Bogus form-number: the source file has probably
                                changed too much to cope with.
    source: NIL
    0]
```

Searching for these errors has proved fruitless.

Comment: To me `getaddrinfo` in the SBCL error suggests that there is a DNS problem or a more general network problem. Quicklisp needs to download systems but there is a problem somewhere there. In the debugger prompt, ie. `0]`, you can write `backtrace` to show a backtrace and have more context

Comment: I think you must be right. Running the backtrace for SBCL gave me 0: (SB-BSD-SOCKETS:NAME-SERVICE-ERROR "getaddrinfo" -3)
1: (SB-BSD-SOCKETS:GET-HOST-BY-NAME #<unavailable argument>)
This, along with some other funny behaviour, makes me think my network setup is a bit screwy. Oh well. Time to contact the admins, I guess. Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Couple of things to consider. I recommend pretty strongly to obtain the Quicklisp installation file directly from quicklisp.org instead of any other source. Also, try tracing SB-BSD-SOCKETS:GET-HOST-BY-NAME to see what host name it is trying to resolve, and then investigate (outside of your Lisp session) what problem there might be with that. Hope this helps, good luck.